# LINQPad taking long time to execute?

Tags: dump, linqpad, gettype

//LINQPad version 4.31 - for me this code takes 1 minute and 40 seconds to execute. Can anyone else //confirm / explain whats going on

var v = new {Name="jon",Age=33};

v.Age.Dump();

v.GetType().Dump();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's instant for me with V4.38.03.

The output from `v.GetType().Dump();` is quite complex due to the anonymous type.  I expect something has been improved in the latest version.

Comment: The latest release (4.31) has some problems with anonymous types, the latest beta (and presumably the next release) fixes that.

Comment: I'm never scared of installing LinqPad betas.  They're always pretty stable.  Just downloading 4.38.06 :-)

Comment: Just downloaded v4.40.03 and initial results are encouraging - Cheers!